# Why loop keep equaling of two variables?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

Why loop translate variable value to another variable that was equated to one which loop should only change?

```
let arrr = [1,1,1,1,1];
let preArrr = [0,0,0,0,0];
preArrr = arrr;

  for (let i=0; i < arrr.length; i++) arrr[i] = i;

console.log(arrr, preArrr) // arrr = [0,1,2,3,4], preArrr = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

forEach loop give me the same result

```
arrr.forEach(function(e, i) { arrr[i] = i })
console.log(arrr, preArrr) // arrr = [0,1,2,3,4], preArrr = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

but if i change array by instant it wont connect

```
let arrr = [1,1,1,1,1];
let preArrr = [0,0,0,0,0];
preArrr = arrr;

  arrr = [0,1,2,3,4]

console.log(arrr, preArrr) // arrr1 = [0,1,2,3,4], preArrr1 = [1,1,1,1,1];
```

so, how to avoid this connection, but still use loop? I`m trying to save previous state of the array

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, what is `arrr1`?

Comment: `preArrr = arrr;` - the original content of `preArrr` is now irrelevant ... you've just set `preArrr` and `arrr` to be the same array ... how about `let preArrr = arrr.slice()` ... now the values are the same, but it's not the same array (note, if the content of `arrr` were objects, then the previous statement isn't quite accurate - but in this case, you're dealing with primitive values i.e. `1`, and not objects)

Comment: @mackenzie-craig sorry, there should be "arrr" of course

Comment: @jaromanda-x i understood, thanx man

Comment: `arrr = [0,1,2,3,4]`   <-  this creates a `new` array,  `preArrr = arrr;`  <- this does not.

Answer (score 1):

Because you changed `preArr` to point at same array as `arr`

That doesn't make a copy when you do `preArr=arr`. Instead both variables are references to the exact same array

If you want to copy the original into `preArr` use `Array#slice()`

```js
let arrr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
let preArrr = arrr.slice();


for (let i = 0; i < arrr.length; i++) arrr[i] = i;

console.log('arrr', JSON.stringify(arrr))
console.log('preArrr', JSON.stringify(preArrr))
```

Comment: It should probably be noted that in the last installment, `preArrr` was first changed to point to the same location, but then `arrr` was changed to point to another location.

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that slice() method doesnt prevent reference to the same array, if an array you want to copy has 2 dimentions

to avoid that:

```
function slice2D(arr) {
  let store = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    store.push(arr[i].slice());
  }
  return store;
}

let pasteArr = slice2D(copyArr);
```